# In C#, what does an expression x = y == z stand for?

Tags: c#

Please forgive me the noob question, but C# is not my native language. In code I took over, I stumbled upon

```cs
var success = true;
success = Upload.Status == FileStatus.Ok;
```

In there, `FileStatus` is of type `enum`, somewhere custom defined. I guess, `success` is essentially non-nullable Boolean. I think that the 2nd line sets `success` to `false` if (and only if) `Upload.Status == FileStatus.Ok`, which would also induce that the latter two variables should be of same type.

Could you please let me know, whether my hypotheses are correct? Also: How is such a construct called? What is it short for?

Comment: If you'd want to set it to false then you'd write if (Upload.Status != FileStatus.Ok) success = false;  Which you might favor, and easier to debug, but the expression is more succinct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`success` is going to be a bool.

It is initialized with true, but  that should be unessesary.

```
var success = true;
```

And will then be set to the result of `(Upload.Status == FileStatus.Ok)` which is a bool.

```
success = Upload.Status == FileStatus.Ok;
```

Think of it as `success = (Upload.Status == FileStatus.Ok);` if that helps.

And yes, it took me a moment to parse it too. I have a profound dislike for people trying to save lines at the cost of readability. I would use this:

```
if(Upload.Status == FileStatus.Ok)
    success = true;
else
    success = false;
```

*Maybe* use the shorter `if` syntax.

Comment: Just a comment with regards to readability: For me, using `var x = y == z;` is idiomatic C# code and not something out of the ordinary, quite the opposite. I would comment on the more verbose way in a code review and propose the shorthand.

Comment: `I have a profound dislike for people trying to save lines at the cost of readability` yet refuse to use `{` `}`.

Comment: @germi Those kinds of Optimisations are something I leave to the Compiler. It can shorten my code to the OP's code for all I care. Not like I have to deal with it.

Comment: @JAD I am acustomed to never write them on 1-liners. There is room between disliking `success = Upload.Status == FileStatus.Ok;` and disliking if someone skips the brackets in the one case you can skip them. The way I write this, I would double the number of lines. Wich would not help readability one bit.

Answer (score 4):

It's assigning the result of an expression to a variable, same as `var x = 1 + 2;` just that in this case the expression is of type `bool`.

Needlessly verbose, this would be the same:

```
bool success;
if (Upload.Status == FileStatus.Ok)
{
    success = true;
}
else
{
    success = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Upload.Status == FileStatus.Ok` evaluates to a `bool`, either true or false. `success` will be assigned the result of that evaluation.

It's no more mystical than `var sum = 4 + 5;` resulting in `sum` being assigned a value of 9.